# LDV 2.5 Maxus: Does the high-pressure fuel pump have a fuse?

Tags: van

LDV 2.5 Maxus. Does not start on key, but runs well on easy start. Does the high-pressure fuel pump have a fuse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high pressure pump is not an electric pump, it is powered by the toothed belt. I would suggest you to do the following:

1. Check that the fuel filter is clean (not the main suspect, but the easiest thing to check)
2. Ask your mechanic for a return flow measurment monitoring of the injectors.

Additional stuff: Check for leaks, abnormal exhaust fumes, rough idling and abnormal engine sounds